# Deploying new version of a SPFX app propagates functionality to web without updating app by user

Tags: spfx, deployment, update, version

After deploying a new version of a SPFX WebPart/Extension to an AppCatalog in SharePoint Online the new funcionality gets propagated to instances of the app installed on webs. But the users still have the possibility to "update" their version of the app on their web by pressing the "GET IT" button in the "About" window of the application in Site Contents page of the web. Even though it doesn't really do anything, they just stop having the "GET IT" button usable and it changes to "ADD IT".